# Is there a name for this variant of the MST and the TSP?

Tags: algorithms, oc.optimization-and-control, terminology, trees, spanning-tree

Suppose I am given a weighted graph $G$ that contains a "start vertex" $v_0$, and my goal is to construct a set of paths that all originate at $v_0$ and touch all of the vertices of $G$, with as minimal total weight as possible.  Is there a name for this?  It's bounded below by the minimum spanning tree of $G$, but bounded above by the travelling salesman tour of $G$, so I'm curious if it's been studied previously in the literature.

Comment: This is similar (but not quite the same) as the *shortest-path tree* constructed by Dijkstra's algorithm.